# Can I live render a UINavigationBar in Xcode 6?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios8, uinavigationbar, xcode6

I have successfully used the live rendering feature in `Xcode 6` to show a `UIView` in `Interface Builder`.

Now I want to use live rendering with a `UINavigationBar`. I have tried to set it up in IB as I did with a `UIView` without success.

Is it possible to live render a `UINavigationBar` in `Xcode 6`, or am I missing something?